# Use .dll from Analog Discovery in uwp

Tags: c#, uwp

I would like to use an external .dll to communicate with a Analog Discovery 2 board. The dwf.dll exposes C API and it is build with VS2008.

If i add the dll to the uwp project and call it with the standard c# wrapper the dwf.dll can not be found. In a WinForms or WPF project everything works well. I know uwp runs in a protected environment and the dll needs to fulfill several conditions. But what would be the easiest way to work with it without rebuilding the dll?

Attached i uploaded an example project at github:
https://github.com/windman11/Ad2_UWP

Answer (score 0):

if you have a WinForm or WPF app that's running fine then you can use that app directly in the uwp app using the desktop bridge and launch that exe or directly package that exe to uwp packaging app and publish to store

for using the desktop bridge to use exe in your uwp look at that https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/06/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-1/

or

directly package your exe to uwp package take a look at that
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net
or
https://youtu.be/fJkbYPyd08w